# PHP Mail Certainty

Tags: php, email, phpmailer, swiftmailer

I've tried different methods of sending mails using PHP.

The problem I always face is that some people are not receiving them.

I've tried different mail libraries like **phpmailer** and **swiftmailer**
But still people are complaining that they did not receive an email (people with the same email client and on the same @url)

I'm wondering is there a way that always works? A way to check if, and if not why the emails aren't being sent to some people.

There should be some way?

### This is a log of a failed sent email. Is there some header info I should add?

```
Return-path: <mailer@mindstretchscan.eu>
Received: from mail.axc.nl ([159.253.0.157]:44252)
    by vserver23.axc.nl with esmtp (Exim 4.82)
    (envelope-from <mailer@mindstretchscan.eu>)
    id 1WCkYY-0003KK-L1
    for ludo.aris@ergo.be; Mon, 10 Feb 2014 07:41:26 +0100
Message-ID: <f155567d1c7a3528386a58b33e6edd4f@mindstretchscan.eu>
Date: Mon, 10 Feb 2014 07:41:26 +0100
Subject: Mindstretch Scan
From: Mindstretch Mailer <mailer@mindstretchscan.eu>
To: ludo.aris@ergo.be
MIME-Version: 1.0
Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8
Content-Transfer-Encoding: quoted-printable
```

Comment: Have you checked your mail logs to see if these emails are being sent at all and if they are accepted by the remote mail server?

Comment: If your messages are considered spam by some mail providers, switching to another library is not going to change that (otherwise, spammers could do exactly that).

Comment: I would say it is almost certain that the code or library choice is not the problem if only users on certain networks are not getting your email. Check your mail server logs as the remote mail server is probably rejecting your email for some reason or it is just silently dropping it.

Comment: where can you normally get the mail logs? thanks!

Comment: Without knowing what mail server on what distribution of what platform, it would be very hard to answer you. Try a google for XXXXX mail log location where XXXXX is what mail server you use

Comment: I already found them thanks! There's not much in them. Only 1 failed email with the reason of "Hop count exceeded", an error caused by outlook

Answer (score 0):

You can try to setup a SPF record, reverse DNS & DKIM. It's also wise to check whether you have been blacklisted/ whether the e-mails are sent. I'm afraid a change of mail library won't help in this case.